# Is eSATA as big a security risk as USB on Windows 7+?

Tags: storage, usb-drive, sata

My current understanding is that USB mass storage devices represent a major potential security and virus risk on Windows due to various forms of auto-execution. Does the same apply to eSATA?

I mean, obviously, connected an unsecured storage system is never fully safe, but does eSATA have the same kind of auto-execution holes that USB has?

Comment: Autoplay in Windows works with various kind of devices. So same goes for USB, eSATA, SD Card, Firewire.

Comment: Is auto execution working on USB mass storage devices for win7+?

Comment: @Silverfox: Yes, sort of. By default, you are presented with a list of options. However, you can select a default and then you won't be prompted.

Comment: isn't eSata a DMA vector? to me, that's worse than USB...

Comment: @Aria I am speaking of more than autoplay. There are some low-level firmware/driver auto-execution holes in USB...aren't there?

Comment: @dandavis If I assume the hardware itself is not malicious (I know, I know), then either eSATA and USB are the same (connect storage device and get auto-infect) or they are treated different (eSATA treated more like a local drive, USB like external). Right?

Comment: if the hardware is not bad the risks from the data are comparable.